# How to concatenate two input fields into one hidden field to pass on form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, hidden-field

I'm trying to create a function that captures first name (req_firstName) and last name (req_lastName) and combines them into one hidden field (req_fullName). When the form is submitted, all three fields would be passed to the database, however something is amiss with my code. The first name and last name fields are passing to the database, but not the full name. Can anyone tell what I'm missing here?

```
<form action="" method="post" target="requestAccessSubmitFrame" role="form" id="requestAccess">
<input name="req_fullName" id="req_fullName" value="" type="hidden">
<input class="form-control" name="req_firstName" id="req_firstName" required aria-required="true" type="text">
<input class="form-control" name="req_lastName" id="req_lastName" required aria-required="true" type="text">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send request</button>


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(function(){
            $("#requestAccess").submit(function(event){
                $('#requestAccessModalBody01').hide();
                $('#requestAccessModalBody02').show();
            });
            $('#req_firstName,#req_lastName').on("keyup",function(){     
                fName = $("#req_firstName").val();  
                lName = $("#req_lastName").val(); 
                fullName = fName + " " + lName;
                $("#req_fullName").val(fullName);
                console.log(fullName);
                console.log("Submitted Request Access");
            });
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: What makes you think the issue is in the form and not server side? What does your debugging show?

Comment: What's the point of even doing that? Just send the first and last and combine them on the server side

Comment: Nothing shows up on console. I also quadruple-checked the server settings (form field name, validation, etc.).

Comment: @j08691 - That's not an option. Long story.

Answer (score 1):

There are in fact no errors in your code shown there. I put it in https://jsfiddle.net/u6q9sn2a/1/

```
<form action="" method="post" target="requestAccessSubmitFrame" role="form" id="requestAccess">
<input name="req_fullName" id="req_fullName" value="" type="hidden">
<input class="form-control" name="req_firstName" id="req_firstName" required aria-required="true" type="text">
<input class="form-control" name="req_lastName" id="req_lastName" required aria-required="true" type="text">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send request</button>
</form>
```

and inspecting the submit request i get:

[image: All paramenters passed]